# Distinct by comparing multiple columns SQL

Tags: sql

I have a select query

```
Select col1,col2,col3 
from table;
```

The table contains following rows

```
col1 col2 col3 
A    | B  | C
B    | A  | C
C    | B  | C
```

I need to get the distinct result which contains a single combination A,B,C by comparing multiple columns.

Result Should be some thing like

```
col1 col2 col3 
A    | B  | C
```

the order can be changed of result rows.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: which RDBMS it is Oracle/mysql/SqlServe ?

Answer (score 2):

Please try out this, I am not sure about you proper requirement. But on sample data given above. I have came across this solution,

```
With CTE as
(
     Select MIN(col1) as col1 from MyTable
)
Select * from CTE
cross apply
    (
        Select MIN(col2) as col2 from MyTable
        where col2 <> CTE.col1
    )as a
cross apply
    (
        Select MIN(col3) as col3 from MyTable
        where col3 not in (CTE.col1,a.col2)
    )as b
```

[DEMO HERE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c646c/4)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (col1 = 'A' AND col2 = 'B' AND col3 = 'C')
```

Comment: OP wants to remove duplicate rows according to all three columns but the order should not matter. You are filtering by static values but apart from the fact that it was just an example it also incorrect because `col3 = 'A' AND col1 = 'B' AND col2 = 'C'` would also be allowed.

Comment: Yes, The values of the columns are not static !

Comment: Can you please add some explanation to your answer?

Comment: This would bring back the single combination A,B,C as requested in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can also go with this below query if the number of column and the values are known.

```
The CASE statement is the closest to IF in SQL

SELECT
         CASE 
              WHEN (col1 = 'A' and col2 = 'B' and col3='C') or (col1 = 'C' and col2 = 'A' and col3='B') or (col1 = 'B' and col2 = 'C' and col3='A' )
                 THEN 1 
              ELSE 0 
         END  as RESULT, * 
FROM table
```

From the result you can take the required output by checking the value of `RESULT==1(integer)`

If you want the `result as a boolean value` then do the `CAST` like ,

```
SELECT
     CAST(
         CASE 
              WHEN (col1 = 'A' and col2 = 'B' and col3='C') or (col1 = 'C' and col2 = 'A' and col3='B') or (col1 = 'B' and col2 = 'C' and col3='A' )
                 THEN 1 
              ELSE 0 
         END  as RESULT_INT)
     as RESUTL, * 
FROM table
```